# Debugger in VS Code for C++ is not working

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, debugging

I tried debugging my code using the debugger in VS Code for C++ and its not showing any of my variables or anything its just blank after running
It just says that breakpoint reached and exits the code
I have tried this debugging online using online compiler but the code just runs and I cannot debug anything 
Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here or is it compiler's fault?
[image: Screenshot of VS Code]

If you want the code its here:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

void spiralOrder(vector<vector<int>> &matrix){

    int left = 0;
    int right = matrix[0].size()-1;
    int top = 0;
    int bottom = matrix.size()-1;

    int direction = 0;

    while(left<=right && top<=bottom){
        // * Left --> Right 
        if(direction==0){
            for(int col=0; col<=right; col++){
                cout<<matrix[top][col]<<" ";
            }
            top++;
        }

        // * Top --> Bottom
        else if(direction==1){
            for(int row=top; row<=bottom; row++){
                cout<<matrix[row][right]<<" ";
            }
            right--;
        }

        // * Right --> Left
        else if(direction==2){
            for(int col=right; col>=left; col--){
                cout<<matrix[bottom][col]<<" ";
            }
            bottom--;
        }

        // * Bottom --> Top
        else{
            for(int row=bottom; row>=top; row--){
                cout<<matrix[row][left]<<" ";
            }
            left++;
        }

        direction = (direction+1)%4;
        // 0, 1, 2, 3
    }

    return;
}


int main(){

    // ? Given an n X m Matrix 'a', return all elements of the matrix in spiral order.

    int n=3, m=3;
    
    // cin>>n>>m;

    // vector<vector<int>> matrix(n, vector<int> (m));
    vector<vector<int>> matrix
    {
        {1, 2, 3},
        {4, 5, 6},
        {7, 8, 9}
    };

    // for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    //     for(int j=0; j<m; j++){
    //         cin>>matrix[i][j];
    //     }
    // }

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<m; j++){
            cout<<matrix[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }

    spiralOrder(matrix);

    
    return 0;
}
```

My launch.json file:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "C/C++ Runner: Debug Session",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "args": [],
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "externalConsole": true,
      "cwd": "d:/Files/Desktop/Programming/C-plus-plus/PhysicsWallah/Lec19_2D_Array_Problems_4",
      "program": "d:/Files/Desktop/Programming/C-plus-plus/PhysicsWallah/Lec19_2D_Array_Problems_4/build/Debug/outDebug",
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "miDebuggerPath": "gdb",
      "setupCommands": [
        {
          "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
          "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
          "ignoreFailures": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Did you install msys2 and use it to install MinGW like the official documentation tells you: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw)

Comment: yes i did it like the instructions told me

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Emphasis on "minimal" and "example".